# fatal error: avr/io.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: gcc, cross-compilation

How to load `avr/io.h` header files in the `gcc` compiler..I'm using 12.04 version of Ubuntu..

When ever i run a AVR program this kind of error is generating

> fatal error: avr/io.h: No such file or directory. compilation terminated."

Answer (score 15):

try installing avr-libc and gcc-avr:

`sudo apt-get install avr-libc gcc-avr`

Then, to compile code for the AVR you need start by compiling it to an executable using: gcc-avr and then link it using avr-objcopy to create a hex file for the device:

`avr-gcc -mmcu=atmegaX yourpgm.c -o yourpgm.elf`

`avr-objcopy -j .text -O ihex yourpgm.elf yourpgm.hex`

Then, the hex file generated is the one to be installed on the device. You can use avrdude to import it. There are a lot more options that you can use for the compiler and linker, I suggest reading the man page for these tools; they are very helpful.